# Azure Http Function with Output binding for a Queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-http, azure-function-queue

I have Http Trigger function in .Net 5.0.

I added output binding to the function to a Queue by following this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-storage-queue-vs?tabs=in-process

I am having an error when I define the Output binding in the multi response class. Can't figure out the napespace for the [QueueOutput( ..
[image]

It may be a small fix but haven't been able to figure it out. There are code snippets over the Web but no working example where I can see which nugget package I am missing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the appropriate package to your project?

Comment: Did you ever have an issue where the function never responds back when the QueueOutput attribute is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "out-of-process" or "isolated" model requires that you install the following nuget package:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage
```

Then, you'll be able to use the QueueOutput Attribute

Comment: Thanks! Yes this worked.